# Replace multiple substrings at once

Tags: java, regex, replace

Say I have a file, that contains some text. There are substrings like "substr1", "substr2", "substr3" etc. in it. I need to replace all of those substrings with some other text, like "repl1", "repl2", "repl3". In Python, I would create a dictionary like this:

```
{
 "substr1": "repl1",
 "substr2": "repl2",
 "substr3": "repl3"
}
```

and create the pattern joining the keys with '|', then replace with `re.sub` function.
Is there a similar simple way to do this in Java?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049528/java-best-way-for-string-find-and-replace

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how your Python-suggestion translates to Java:

```
Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("substr1", "repl1");
    put("substr2", "repl2");
    put("substr3", "repl3");
}};

String input = "lorem substr1 ipsum substr2 dolor substr3 amet";

// create the pattern joining the keys with '|'
String regexp = "substr1|substr2|substr3";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacements.get(m.group()));
m.appendTail(sb);


System.out.println(sb.toString());   // lorem repl1 ipsum repl2 dolor repl3 amet
```

---

This approach does a **simultanious** (i.e. "at once") replacement. I.e., if you happened to have

```
"a" -> "b"
"b" -> "c"
```

then this approach would give `"a b" -> "b c"` as opposed to the answers suggesting you should chain several calls to `replace` or `replaceAll` which would give `"c c"`.

---

(If you generalize this approach to create the regexp programatically, make sure you `Pattern.quote` each individual search word and `Matcher.quoteReplacement` each replacement word.)

Comment: How does this approach differ from StringUtils.replaceEach? Or is replaceEach the same as replaceAll?

Comment: This approach is more general as you can provide an arbitrary replacement-function (look at the `m.appendReplacement` line). Secondly it doesn't required you to include a third party library for the sake of a string-manipulation routine. (If you already depend on the Apache Commons, or don't bother at all with another dependency, then go with the `replaceEach` approach.)

Comment: (No, `replaceEach` is not the same as `replaceAll`. `replaceAll` is just a regexp-version of `replace`.)

Comment: Does replaceEach play with those "a b" -> "b c" the same as your solution?

Comment: Your solution sounds better than replaceEach, however, I still need to find a way to join the keys of a map to create the pattern programatically. The simplest way I see to do this is to use join() from StringUtils :)

Comment: Heheh good point. I'm not sure join will help you though. You need to quote the keys / values. (See my last note.) Unless you find a way to do with without loops, you could just as well join the stings while performing the quoting :-)

Comment: "join the stings while performing the quoting" What do you mean?

Comment: For my approach to work, you need to use `Pattern.quote` on the keys. In other words, you'll have to loop over the keys either way. (StringUtils.join won't save you from looping!)

Comment: `StringBuffer` is synchronized, in this case it's better to use `StringBuilder`

Comment: Please avoid using `new HashMap<>() {{ /*puts*/ }};` in answers. A lot of people do not know the the adverse negative side-effect of this method of Map initialization in frequently executed code.

Comment: @Czar, what adverse negative side-effects are you talking about?

Comment: @aioobe, short summary: https://dzone.com/articles/double-brace-initialization
Or just google `double brace initialization antipattern` for more info

Comment: I don't think an extra .class file matters much here. (You already have them everywhere for anonymous listener implementations etc.) I don't really get the argument about lacking support for diamond operator. Double-brace initialization still saves characters, right? Also, diamond operators for anonymous classes is supported in Java 9.

Answer (score 7):

[`StringUtils.replaceEach`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[]%29) in the [Apache Commons Lang project](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), but it works on Strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString.replace("substr1", "repl1")
          .replace("substr2", "repl2")
          .replace("substr3", "repl3");
```

Comment: +1... That's not "all at once" though. If the the example was different, say `"a" -> "b"` and `"b" -> "c"` then there would be no `b`s in the result, even though there were `a`s in the input.

Comment: @aioobe: `StringUtils.replaceEach()` handles this well.

Answer (score 2):

First, a demonstration of the problem:

```
String s = "I have three cats and two dogs.";
s = s.replace("cats", "dogs")
    .replace("dogs", "budgies");
System.out.println(s);
```

This is intended to replace cats => dogs and dogs => budgies, but the sequential replacement operates on the result of the previous replacement, so the unfortunate output is:

> I have three budgies and two budgies.

Here's my implementation of a simultaneous replacement method. It's easy to write using [`String.regionMatches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches%28boolean,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29):

```
public static String simultaneousReplace(String subject, String... pairs) {
    if (pairs.length % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Strings to find and replace are not paired.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int numPairs = pairs.length / 2;
    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < subject.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numPairs; j++) {
            String find = pairs[j * 2];
            if (subject.regionMatches(i, find, 0, find.length())) {
                sb.append(pairs[j * 2 + 1]);
                i += find.length() - 1;
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        sb.append(subject.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Testing:

```
String s = "I have three cats and two dogs.";
s = simultaneousReplace(s,
    "cats", "dogs",
    "dogs", "budgies");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> I have three dogs and two budgies.

Additionally, it is sometimes useful when doing simultaneous replacement, to make sure to look for the longest match. (PHP's [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function does this, for example.) Here is my implementation for that:

```
public static String simultaneousReplaceLongest(String subject, String... pairs) {
    if (pairs.length % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Strings to find and replace are not paired.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int numPairs = pairs.length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < subject.length(); i++) {
        int longestMatchIndex = -1;
        int longestMatchLength = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < numPairs; j++) {
            String find = pairs[j * 2];
            if (subject.regionMatches(i, find, 0, find.length())) {
                if (find.length() > longestMatchLength) {
                    longestMatchIndex = j;
                    longestMatchLength = find.length();
                }
            }
        }
        if (longestMatchIndex >= 0) {
            sb.append(pairs[longestMatchIndex * 2 + 1]);
            i += longestMatchLength - 1;
        } else {
            sb.append(subject.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Why would you need this? Example follows:

```
String truth = "Java is to JavaScript";
truth += " as " + simultaneousReplaceLongest(truth,
    "Java", "Ham",
    "JavaScript", "Hamster");
System.out.println(truth);
```

Output:

> Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster

If we had used `simultaneousReplace` instead of `simultaneousReplaceLongest`, the output would have had "HamScript" instead of "Hamster" :)

Note that the above methods are case-sensitive. If you need case-insensitive versions it is easy to modify the above because `String.regionMatches` can take an `ignoreCase` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
    return yourString.replaceAll("substr1","relp1").
                     replaceAll("substr2","relp2").
                     replaceAll("substr3","relp3")
```

Comment: -1. This isn't all at once, and unnecessarily uses a regex method (replaceAll) instead of the plain String method (replace).