# Replace Array String with Other Array String

Tags: java

same topic : [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

I want to replace `String Replace = "SUM(NewCounter)+SUM(NewCounter2)+NewCounter3";`

I have `Array A = {NewCounter, NewCounter2, NewCounter3}`
say I have `Array B = {test, testA, testB}`

I want to replace it with array `A` with array `B` in String `Replace`.
I try to use method *`ReplaceAll(A.get(index), B.get(index));`*

**Problem is:**

`NewCounter2` is Read by system `"NewCounter"+2`
so I have result = `String Replace = "SUM(test)+SUM(test2)+test3";`

I try to use ' in Character NewCounter, it will be `Array A = {'NewCounter', 'NewCounter2', 'NewCounter3'}`

but I must change String `Replace` Before like this :

```
String Replace = "SUM('NewCounter')+SUM('NewCounter2')+'NewCounter3'";
```

Is there other way to me ???
I don't want to change String before...

Thanksfull,

-mazipan-

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: It is very hard to figure out what your question means.

Comment: Duplicate of [Replace multiple substrings in a file at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661460/replace-multiple-substrings-in-a-file-at-once).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution for simultaneous replacement is to process the strings in order of decreasing length. This will do the replacements correctly:

```
A = {NewCounter3, NewCounter2, NewCounter}
B = {testB, testA, test}
```

This technique won't work if any of the search strings could match the replacement strings, however.

Edit: For the general case, I've written this:

```
public static String simultaneousReplace(String subject,
        String[] find, String[] replace) {
    if (find.length != replace.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Strings to find and replace are not paired.");
    int numPairs = find.length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, len = subject.length(); i < len; i++) {
        int longestMatchIndex = -1;
        int longestMatchLength = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < numPairs; j++) {
            String find1 = find[j];
            if (subject.regionMatches(false, i, find1, 0, find1.length())) {
                if (find1.length() > longestMatchLength) {
                    longestMatchIndex = j;
                    longestMatchLength = find1.length();
                }
            }
        }
        if (longestMatchIndex >= 0) {
            sb.append(replace[longestMatchIndex]);
            i += longestMatchLength - 1;
        } else {
            sb.append(subject.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example usage:

```
String s = "SUM(NewCounter)+SUM(NewCounter2)+NewCounter3";

s = simultaneousReplace(s,
    new String[] { "NewCounter", "NewCounter2", "NewCounter3" },
    new String[] { "test", "testA", "testB" }
);

System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
SUM(test)+SUM(testA)+testB
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I want.
but this is problem a long time ago.
I even forget about this problem.
thanks @Boann

Answer (score 0):

If SUM is just a String and not a method then you can use:

```
String Replace = "SUM(" + NewCounter + ")SUM(" + NewCounter2 +")" + NewCounter3;
```

If Sum is a method then you can use

```
 String Replace = SUM(NewCounter) + SUM(NewCounter2) + NewCounter3;
```

Although for the second one you may have to cast/convert to a string by surrounding it with

```
().toString()
```

or by adding

```
(String)()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache's commons-lang `StringUtils#replaceEach` handles these problems elegantly.

**Runnable Code :**

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
     String replace = "SUM(NewCounter)+SUM(NewCounter2)+NewCounter3";
     String [] a = { "NewCounter", "NewCounter2", "NewCounter3" };
     String [] b = { "test", "testA", "testB" };

     System.out.println(StringUtils.replaceEach(replace, a, b));
}
```

Will give you

`SUM(test)+SUM(test2)+test3`

Comment: "SUM(test)+SUM(test2)+test3" is exactly not what OP wants.

Comment: I think that is what the OP wants.

Comment: He wants "SUM(test)+SUM(testA)+testB".

Comment: If that is the case, I agree with first part of your answer to process the strings in order of decreasing length. The OP's question for me is blurry though, and how I understand it, he wants `SUM(test)+SUM(test2)+test3`. Im gonna upvote your answer for this (side note : I'm not the one who gave that downvote).